# Padding issue in jssor slider captions

Tags: css, jssor

I used padding in captions of jssor slider but I saw that it cause issues in captions and content of some of captions does not show correctly.
This is the code that I applied padding.

```
.captionOrange, .captionBlack {
color: #fff;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

I used this code in `introduction-slider.source.html` inside `demos-jquery`.
When I use `position: relative;` for captions it fix above issue but it ignores `top` css property and did not use top of caption parent.
This is an image of issue.
[image]

**Update:**
There is an slider on top of below link and it's my mean. Please inspect one of captions in it and you can see a css rule `.captionOrange, .captionBlue, .captionBlack, .captionSymbol` so please add `padding: 20px` to it to see result. When you add `padding: 20px` it will cut some of captions content.
[jssor slider introduction theme](http://jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html)

Comment: Need more info: like the element that contains the captions or whatever else surrounds the caption that might be applicable. you should post a Fiddle maybe?

Comment: @zer00ne I updated question, please look at update.

Comment: Delete the line-height property.

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga Did you fixed this issue by deleting line-height, how? Please not that first add padding and then removing line-height. I removed line-height but I could not get answer!

Comment: Put all your code in a jsfiddle and i will check it to fix the problem ;)

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga There is an example in http://jssor.com/demos/introduction-slider.html

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see the reason why moving the captions get you those results. I looked at the top left one called `.captionOrange`:

```
<div u="caption" t="CLIP|LR" du="1500" class="captionOrange" style="position: absolute; left: 20px; top: 30px; width: 500px; height: 30px; clip: rect(0px 500px 30px 0px);"> 
Touch swipe and responsive javascript image slider
</div>
```

At the end of this tag notice the following part:

```
clip: rect(0px 500px 30px 0px);
```

This is a `clip` rectangle 500px wide and 30px tall (height), increase the 30px to whatever you want and you'll have more room for text. See this [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/) for details on the `clip` property. Basically the `clip` property will create a window that determines what is visible within an element.

Comment: Yes this issue occurs in some caption transitions like  CLIP, MCLIP, etc. For clip css style it's created by Jssor slider and I have not control on it. It seems that Jssor slider does not consider padding for creating clip style!

Comment: @taher JSSOR has an extensive API go [**here**](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html) and look at the bottom.

Comment: @taher If the API doesn't work for some reason you can go [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=jssor) as well.

Comment: I tried to fix this issue by adding padding to width and height of captions but it caused design issues, because I developed a Wordpress plugin and users set width and height of captions so when I change width and height of captions by code it cause some design issues!

Comment: @taher You have my sympathies, Wordpress and it's ilk are like a web developer's Limbo. I'm afraid I can't be much help when it involves styling in CMSs and prefab blogs. My advice would be only educated guesses since I never dealt with prefab environments.  I find the limitations far exceed the convenience.

Comment: -[Sorry I exceeded the 5min limit]-  For what it's worth, I would try wrapping the text in a span then assign it `position: absolute` and `index: *n* +` (n=the highest number). You might try wrapping that in a `<div style="position: relative;">` if the previous doesn't work.

Comment: I tried both solutions but I could not fix issue, because as you can see it cuts caption not it's text content, background-color cutted as well.

Comment: @taher `clip: rect(0px 500px 30px 0px);` change to `clip: rect(0px 500px 80px 0px);` with this: `window.onload = tallClip(80); function tallClip(x) { var z = parseInt(x, 10); $('.captionOrange').css('clip', '0px 500px '+z+'px 0px');}` Like I said before, I cannot be very accurate, I'm not familiar with the ins and outs of WP.

Comment: I used this solution but it does not works because clip override by Jssor slider, so I think best solution for this issue is fixing it in core of Jssor slider, I changed some codes of Jssor slider for fixing it and it worked. I reported this issue to Jssor Slider in github. @zer00ne Thank you so much for your guides and help.

Comment: @taher My pleasure, don't forget to accept my answer so other users that experience this problem will know why.

Comment: Add css `box-sizing:border-box;` for the element.